# Workaround equivalent of "inputname" to return structure name?

Tags: matlab

I know that, inside a MATLAB function,  `inputname(k)` will return the k-th argument **iff**  the argument is a variable name.  Is there any way to write some parsing code that can retrieve the full input argument when that argument is a structure, e.g.  `foo.bar` ?    The reason I want to be able to do this is that I'm writing some tools for generic use where the input could be either a named variable or a named structure element.

My primary intent is to be able to store and return the input argment(s) as part of a structure or other variable that the function returns.  This is a 'chain of custody' feature which makes it easier for me or others to verify the source data sets used to generate the output data sets.

I don't want the user to have to self-parse externally, or to have to deal with some kludge like

```
function doit(name,fieldname)
    if(exist('fieldname','var'))
        name = name.(fieldname);
        myinput = [inputname(1),inputname(2)];
    else
       myinput = inputname(1);
    end

% do the function stuff
```

(I call this a kludge because it both requires the user to enter strange arguments and because it fouls up the argument sequence for functions with multiple inputs)

Comment: In your `doit` function where does `inputname` come from and what does `name` do if it's not a `struct`?  I'm not really following what your inputs are and their purpose.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context here about what you're doing with this?

Comment: What does it matter if it's a field of a struct? Are you trying to use `assignin` as some place inside of your code to push the result back to them?

Comment: @Matt `inputname` is a MATLAB function which returns the name of the item entered as an argument to the function.

Comment: @Suever please see added info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no support from the language to get the input names when passing structs. The reason is probably `x.a` is internally a call to `subsref` which returns a new variable, all context is lost. The only possibility you have is using the debug tools and parse the code. There is no other option.

```
function x=f(varargin)
[ST, I] = dbstack('-completenames', 1);
if numel(ST)>0
    fid=fopen(ST(1).file,'r');
    for ix=2:ST(1).line;fgetl(fid);end
    codeline=fgetl(fid);
    fclose(fid);
    fprintf('function was called with line %s\n',codeline);
else
    fprintf('function was called from base workspace\n');
end
end
```

From there you may try to parse the code line to get the individual argument names.

Answer (score 0):

Far uglier than  Daniel's approach, and probably will crash on the wrong OS, but here's a hack that works to retrieve the first argument; easily adjusted to retrieve all arguments.

```
  [~,myname] = system('whoami');
    myname = strtrim(myname(4:end)); % removes domain tag in my Windows envir
    % sorry about " \' " fouling up SO's color parsing
    myloc = ['C:\Users\' , myname ,  '\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB\R2015a\History.xml'] ;
    f = fopen(myloc,'r');
    foo = fscanf(f,'%s');
    fclose(f);
    pfoo = findpat(foo,'myFunctionName'); 
    % just look for the last instance
    namstart = find(foo(pfoo(end):(pfoo(end)+30)) =='(',1) +pfoo(end);
    % catch either ')' or ',' 
    namend(1) = find(foo((namstart):end)== ')',1) -2 +namstart;
    if numel(find(foo((namstart):end)== ',',1)),
         namend(2) = find(foo((namstart):end)== ',',1) -2 +namstart;
    end
    thearg = foo(namstart:(min(namend)) );
```

Comment: You could use `myloc=fullfile(getenv('appdata'),'MathWorks','MATLAB',version('-release'),'History.xml')`

Comment: You can not rely on the command history to be flushed immediately to file, better use `com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory` which returns a javaArray of strings with the commands.